# How to make use of Eclipse JPA dialect after configuration?

Tags: eclipselink

```
public interface FruitRepository extends CrudRepository<Article, Long>  {
    List<Fruit> findByTitle(String Fruit);
}

public LocalContainerEntitymanager entityManagerFactory() {
      .. 
      em.setJpaDialect(new EclipseLinkJpaDialect());
}

@Service
public class FruitService {
    @Autowired
    private FruitRepository fruitRepository;
    @Override
    public Fruit getFruitById(long fruitId) {
        testFruitObj = fruitRepository.findById(fruitId).get();
        testFruitObj.setFruitName("This is an apple");             --> At this point testFruitObj is saved as "This is an apple" in database. 
        fruitObj = fruitRepository.findById(fruitId).get();
        return fruitObj;
    }
}
```

May I check how to integrate the Eclipse JPA Dialect beginTransaction() methods so that entity can be detached?

Fruit name is change to "This is an apple" without saving. Is there any ways to overcome this?

Comment: Are you sure it is saved at that point? EclipseLink will not save anything to the database unless something forces the statement to the database, which occurs when something forces a flush (explicit or some queries require it) on the EntityManager that loaded that instance. And it won't be saved to the database until the transaction commits. Could it just be that these changes are being seen by other calls because you are reusing the same EntityManager instance over and over?  Try getting a new one, or clearing it at logical points. Clearing it is similar to detaching everything in it.

Comment: Hi currently the above implementation does not have the EntityManager. How can i make use of Eclipse JPA Dialect beginTransaction() ?

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite understand what you are asking for in relation to the problem of detachment. If you don't have a transaction context, nothing is saved. Why do you want beginTransaction() access, and how is that going to help detach something? Your issue is that fruitRepository is using the same EntityManager em instance for both findbyId lookups, so returning the same instance. Just call em.clear() in your repository to detach it within a findById method before returning the instance - maybe create a findandDetachById method for it

Comment: hi Chris, may i know what do i detach it because the repo is using Spring data default method. There is no method body

Comment: That is spring boilerplate code. If you want it detached, create your own clear on the repository - something that just takes the injected EntityManager em and calls clear on it.